# Strange appearance of JSVGCanvas

Tags: java, canvas, svg, batik

I use some svg files to create three buttons, but sometimes I get the following result

[image]

instead of the correct one which is this

[image]

This is happening randomly to some JSVGCanvas I have on my program. (The svg is moved down and right so only the 1/4 of it is showing)
I also used some listeners of JSVGCanvas to check if they have been rendered and built correctly and both actions had been completed.

Any ideas why is this happening ?

Comment: You're going to need to create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue if you want us to help you.

Comment: The problem is that this bug does not appear always so even if I make an example, it is not sure to be bugged. Plus, svg items, libraries and many lines of code are needed to make even a small example like this. So this is why I am asking people who have used already JSVGCanvas if they had any bug like this one

Comment: Well our problem is that without such a thing we can't help you. Even if someone has seen something like this before, their cause may be different to yours.

Comment: of course you are right but I could try their solution.